# Did Tuvok, B'Elanna, and Janeway live the rest of their lives with Borg implants/technology inside of them?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, borg

ST Voyager "Unimatrix Zero":

> Chief medical officer's log, stardate 54014.4. It's been forty eight
>   hours since the away team returned to Voyager. Thanks to the neural
>   suppressant, I've been able to **extract most of their Borg
>   technology**. The Captain and B'Elanna are on the mend, but Tuvok will
>   need a little more time to recover.
>
> [Sickbay]
>
> SEVEN: General Korok is finished with his repairs. He's already been
>   contacted by another Borg vessel in the region. It's also under the
>   control of former drones.
>
> JANEWAY: The Doctor removed my spinal clamps but it'll be a while
>   before I'm playing hoverball again. If I ever imply it's been easy on
>   you these last few years, remind me about today.

The doctor said he was able to remove most of the Borg Technology from their bodies.

Do they have Borg technology inside of them for the rest of their lives, if so what parts?

I also wonder if they now have this weird relationship like seven does to the collective since they have Borg technology inside of them.

Comment: If you could get a hold of [this book](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Farther_Shore) it might be useful

Comment: @N_Soong is that canon?

Comment: Nup, but I don't think there's any further canon reference to them

Comment: @N_Soong is that book considered fanfic or was it official in some way? did you read it?

Comment: I haven't read it and I don't know whether it's licensed (probably is actually considering it's on MB), but it might be useful - just saying

Answer (score 8):

In TV canon, they never explicitly state the doctor has removed all trace of the Borg implants.

But it can be inferred that eventually the doctor removes all the Borg implants (or as much as Federation science allows).  As the assimilated crew did not develop relying on those implants as Seven did their natural systems were able to take over all body functions with assistance from the Doctor.  Looking at Picard, after his assimilation and rescue, borg implants remained.  Those implants were reactivated in First Contact to allow the Borg Queen limited access to Picard.  In Endgame both Janeway's are examined and there is no mention of Borg implants in their comparison. We discover that Adm. Janeway does have a piece of modified Borg technology that allows for direct mental interface with computers.  She uses that to communicate with the Queen, but if she had the level of remaining implants that Picard did she wouldn't need it.

Multiple times the Doctor is shown to have a far better grasp of Borg implants than the Federation as the series progresses.  It is also revealed in Human Error (s7e18) it is possible for Seven to remove more of her implants with extensive (and hazardous) surgery, but she does not actually embark on them until Endgame (s7e25) in response to her relationship with Chakotay.

With the ability to remove any implants that don't effect biological function, and eventually the ability to remove those that do, leaving the implants in longer then absolutely necessary would constitute a liability both in the health of the crewmember, and when facing the Borg (as it was for Picard in First Contact).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've watched every episode of voyager multiple times and don't remember any of your references. Can you include relevant quotes from the episodes that shows that he removed anything more after the quote I put in my question? Thanks

Comment: Having just looked over the [Voyager: Human Error's script](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/715.htm), it looked like all the references to the word "implant" were based on a holodeck simulation.  That might imply that further implant removal was a potential reality being explored, but it could also have just been an element of fantasy being used to simplify things while Seven decided to explore how deeper social interactions might affect her.  [Voyager: Endgame's script](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/722.htm) contains the word "implant" but not in reference to Borg implants.